# Creating HTML5 Boilerplate conditional HTML classes in Slim

Tags: html5boilerplate, slim-lang

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses the following conditional `<html>` classes:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

I'm wondering how I can reproduce this in a [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/)-based template.

Here's what I have so far:

```
doctype html
/! paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/
/[ if lt IE 7 ]
    html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"
/[ if IE 7 ]
    html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"
/[ if IE 8 ]
    html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"
/[ if (gte IE 9)|!(IE) ]
    html class="no-js" lang="en"
head
```

The last conditional is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can use the pipe character to escape processing.

```
| <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]<!-->
   <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

See the [Line Indicators](http://rdoc.info/github/stonean/slim/master/file/README.md#Line_indicators) section of the API docs.